# mysqli::error Vs. mysqli_stmt:error

Tags: php, mysqli

Does [mysqli::error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) encompass [mysqli_stmt::error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php)? If an error occurs preparing a statement or executing a statement will myqli::error contain the error or will the error only be contained in mysqli_stmt::error?

EDIT: Just for clarities sake Im trying to understand if I need to check specifically mysqli_stmt::error to handle and report failures or if mysqli::error could be used throughout without missing any errors.

EDIT 2: If the errors are seperate which should be used for mysqli::stmt_init() failures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'yabadaba', 'testdb');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('MESSUP(?'); //no error thrown
var_dump($mysqli->error); //... right syntax to use near 'MESSUP(?'
```

Although there is an [Exception class](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php) - i can't seem to find any method actually throwing it. Looks like everything is in `$mysqli->error`.

Comment: Any chance you can show me where your looking? Id  rather look into it then rewrite half t error checking on a class again

Comment: well, [here](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) : **most recent MySQLi function call** - that would mean `mysqli_*`; but if you really want to double check that - run the functions you use in a fail-like manner and inspect `$mysqli->error`

Comment: If you want mysqli to throw exceptions, set [mysqli_report](http://php.net/function.mysqli-report.php) accordingly.